# How to solve this logically

Tags: java

I have set and a sub-set for each id. i need to accumulate the total

ex: employeeIdSet is the outer set which has all the employeeIds

Now each employee - may be combined or not combined and they will be added credits

```
empa - credit 10
empb linked with empc, empd - credit would be 15,  overall for the 3 employees.
```

similalrly
    empe linked with empz, emps - credit would be 7, over all for the 3 employees and linked with empq where the credit is 9
similarly
    empr linked with empo - credit would be 6, overall for the 2 employees

Now i want to have a list of employee id with respective credits

ex:

```
empa-10
emp-15,
empc-15,
empd-15,
empe - 7+9,
empz - 7+9,
emps- 7+9,
empr - 6,
empo - 6
```

the problem we get employee id in the outer loop and inner loop we can get the subsequent employees. however all addition leads to problem

```
code 
 final Set<Long> combinedEmployeeIdSet = new HashSet<>();
 final Set<CombinedEmployee> combinedEmployees = employee.getCombinedEmployees();
        for(final CombinedEmployee combinedEmployee: combinedEmployees) {
            combinedEmployeeIdSet.add(combinedEmployee.getId());
        }
  for(final OtherEmployee otherEmployee: otherEmployees) {
            if(!combinedEmployeeIdSet.contains(otherEmployee.getId())) {
     employeeCredit += otherEmployee.getCredit();
   }
        }

expectation is get the total credits of the given employeeId where when there under same group, it should be added as one single unit, else the credit should be added
  empe - 7+9, displays 15 
  empz - 7+9, displays 15
  emps- 7+9,  displays 15
```

thanks

Comment: Do you initialize `employeeCredit` before the second `for` loop in the code you posted in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Very confused by your description.

Do you mean you have some "emp"s, say: emp-a,emp-b ... emp-x, and each emp have a credit, say: emp-a:10, emp-b:5, emp-c:7... emp-x:6. Some emps have links with other emps, say: emp-a (emp-b, empc). Now you want to get the credit for each emp, if the emp has links, its credit should be a sumarize of itself and all its links.

So you may get

```
emp-a   10+5+7
emp-b   5
emp-c   7
...
emp-x   6
```

Comment: empa-10
emp-15,
empc-15,
empd-15,
empe - 7+9 = 16,
empz - 7+9 = 16,
emps- 7+9 = 16,
empr - 6,
empo - 6